# Can I get the name of submit button in another form?

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

I have a form which has 3 submit buttons. Their names are generated and assigned in a loop. Now if I use a post method, how can access the name of the submit button which was clicked.

The following is the example of my code:

```
**one.php**

    <form name="one" method="post" action="two.php">

    <?php
    while($i=1;$i<=3;$i=$+1)
    {
    ?>
    <button type="submit" name="<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $i ?>" >
    </button>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </form>

**two.php**

    {
    code???????
    }
```

May be I can use onsubmit attribute for the button tag in one.php, but I am unable to get the output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You could just check in `$_POST` if there is an entry with the name of each one of your three buttons :

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<=3 ; $i++) {
    if (isset($_POST[$i])) {
        // here, you are on the clicked button
    }
}
```

Note that I'd suggest you give better names *(that don't begin with a number)* to your buttons -- which means generating your form like this :

```
<?php for ($i=1 ; $i<=3 ; $i++) { ?>
<button type="submit" name="button_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $i ?>" >
</button>
<?php } ?>
```

And, on form's submission, using something like this :

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<=3 ; $i++) {
    if (isset($_POST['button_' . $i])) {
        // here, you are on the clicked button
    }
}
```

*BTW: your `while` loop's syntax is incorrect -- it seems you've mixed up [`while`][1] and [`for`][2] ;-)*

Comment: that works in everything except IE. IE (at least version 6 and below, I've not tried it with anything more recent) will have the value set for all of the buttons regardless of whether they were clicked. Almost like using a hidden input.

Answer (score 1):

Generate another input element

```
<input type="hidden" name="buttonId" value="<?php echo $i ?>" />
```

And then get your id with `$_REQUEST['buttonId']`