# Can I get the name of submit button in another form?

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the name of submit button in another form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556043/can-i-get-the-name-of-submit-button-in-another-form)

Hi,

I have a form which has 3 submit buttons. Their names are generated and assigned in a loop. Now if I use a post method, how can access the name of the submit button which was clicked.

The following is the example of my form:

```
<form name="one" method="post" action="two.php">

<?php
while($i=1;$i<=3;$i=$+1)
{
?>
<button type="submit" name="<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $i ?>" >
</button>
<?php
}
?>

</form>
```

May be I can use onsubmit attribute for the button tag in one.php, but I am unable to get the output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I've reformatted your code for you.  You should [check out this document on how to format your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), so you won't have to do that wacky replace-brackets-with-parens thing any longer.

Comment: Can you give a little more context about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please post the OUTPUT HTML. What PHP is doing doesn't matter. The issue is on the client, not the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can examine the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/%24_POST) array to see which number was sent through.

How you do that is entirely up to you, it could be as basic as a few [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) checks.

```
if (isset($_POST['1'])) {
    echo "Clicked button 1";
}
if (isset($_POST['2'])) {
    echo "Clicked button 2";
}
if (isset($_POST['3'])) {
    echo "Clicked button 3";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably make more sense to use the same name and different values for multiple submit buttons.

```
<form name="one" method="post" action="two.php">
<?php
while($i=1;$i<=3;$i=$+1)
{
  echo "<input type='submit' name='submitButton' value='{$i}' />";
}
?>
</form>
```

In `two.php` you can then simply pull the value of the submit button that was pressed using `$_POST['submitButton']`