# Get the name of a html submit button via CGI

Tags: c++, html, cgi

I have two submit buttons in a CGI script (in C++). One (`value=Submit`) simply saves the form data. The other one (`value=Save and Reboot`) is supposed to save the form data the same way and then reboot.

Essentially, I want to do this:

```
 if(method == "POST")
 {
   //element 1 saved

   //element 2 saved

   //etc etc

   if(second button is pushed)
     //handle reboot code
  }
```

But how do I tell which button was pushed? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556043/can-i-get-the-name-of-submit-button-in-another-form), but it's in php. I'm working in a C++ CGI script. I've been reading through the [CGICC documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/doc/cgicc_tutorial.html), but I can't find anything on identifying which button was pressed.

To be clear, both buttons essentially will do the same thing (a 'POST'), but I need to be able to identify the button so I can reboot if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that you have two buttons, one **named** "Submit", and one named "Save and Reboot":

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
    <input type="submit"  name="Save and reboot" />
</form>
```

Now, just check if there is a value set in the POST data with the appropriate name:

```
form_iterator fsubmit = formData.getElement("Submit");
if( !fsubmit->isEmpty() && fsubmit != (*formData).end()) {
   // The sumbit is pressed
}

form_iterator fsaveandreboot = formData.getElement("Save and reboot");
if( !fsaveandreboot->isEmpty() && fsaveandreboot != (*formData).end()) {
   // The save and reboot is pressed
}
```

This is very easy to write once that you understand that the button that was not clicked will not be included in the POST data.

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!